# Upgrading ActiveMQ broker without changing version of APIs used by publishers/consumers

Tags: activemq-classic

We have an installation of ActiveMQ version 5.5.1 which we would like to upgrade to 5.10.x in order to fix various bugs.

The broker is connected to JBoss 5.1.0 consumers via the resource adapter and messages are published to it via activemq-all, both version 5.5.1.

Do we need to upgrade these dependencies or can clients continue to use the 5.5.1 versions?

I have seen talk of backwards compatibility with upgrading the clients to a newer version while keeping the broker on an older version, but not the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "compability matrix" with all possible scenarios but it works pretty good with older clients -> newer brokers. 5.6 -> 5.9.1 works very well but I've seen older clients in critical setups too.

If you stay in the 5.x versions you should be ok, but give it a test spin first. It's always good to do some extra testing.